# Conditional logic based on Flask Principal

Tags: python, flask, flask-principal

Is there a way to access the flask principal in order to execute some code conditionally?

In a functiod, I'd like to do something like:

```
def load_some_stuff():

  if <user is an admin>:
      load_report_data()
  #more code, render template etc...
```

then in the template:

```
{% if report_data %}
   // report rendering code goes here
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Flask-Principal's context manager usage:

```
admin_permission = Permission(RoleNeed('admin'))

with not admin_permission.require():
    do_something()
```